# Connect PHP Client to Java backend

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge, cross-language

I need to connect PHP client code to JAVA backend, where the actions are :
 1. http request will be sent from PHP client.
 2. It will interact with JAVA code on Model and will store data in Nosql using JAVA backend

I read about this [php-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php)
Which can be better PHP-JAVA bridge to use?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Project Zero](http://www.projectzero.org/) and [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/). Both of those may be helpful. The php-java bridge that you linked to may prove most useful though as its built to work with the official PHP distribution.